# Triangle partitioning

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computational-geometry

This was a problem in the 2010 Pacific ACM-ICPC contest. The gist of it is trying to find a way to partition a set of points inside a triangle into three subtriangles such that each partition contains exactly a third of the points.

**Input:**

- Coordinates of a bounding triangle: `(v1x,v1y),(v2x,v2y),(v3x,v3y)`
- A number `3n < 30000` representing the number of points lying inside the triangle
- Coordinates of the `3n` points: `(x_i,y_i)` for `i=1...3n`

**Output:**

- A point `(sx,sy)` that splits the triangle into 3 subtriangles such that each subtriangle contains exactly `n` points.

The way the splitting point splits the bounding triangle into subtriangles is as follows: Draw a line from the splitting point to each of the three vertices. This will divide the triangle into 3 subtriangles.

We are guaranteed that such a point exists. Any such point will suffice (the answer is not necessarily unique).

Here is an example of the problem for `n=2` (6 points). We are given the coordinates of each of the colored points and the coordinates of each vertex of the large triangle. The splitting point is circled in gray.

[image]

Can someone suggest an algorithm faster than `O(n^2)`?

Comment: You should ask this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is an algorithms question, not a math question.

Comment: I'd use a simplex-like method.

Comment: Are all the coordinates integer?

Comment: I wonder if the center of mass is always a solution.

Comment: @Alex: it's rarely the solution...

Comment: I am assuming you *need* an algorithm faster then O(n^2)... What were the input bounds on the problem statement?

Comment: @missingno: `n` is bounded by 10,000

Comment: @Alex: No, the coordinates can be floating point numbers.

Comment: Where's the proof that such a point(s) exists? It might give some insight into the problem

Comment: @killogre: It is not guaranteed to exist for any general input. It's just that for the purposes of this problem, the test cases will only contain inputs where such at least one such point exists.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `O(n log n)` algorithm. Let's assume no degeneracy.

The high-level idea is, given a triangle `PQR`,

```
   P
  C \
 /  S\
R-----Q
```

we initially place the center point `C` at `P`. Slide `C` toward `R` until there are `n` points inside the triangle `CPQ` and one (`S`) on the segment `CQ`. Slide `C` toward `Q` until either triangle `CRP` is no longer deficient (perturb `C` and we're done) or `CP` hits a point. In the latter case, slide `C` away from `P` until either triangle `CRP` is no longer deficient (we're done) or `CQ` hits a point, in which case we begin sliding `C` toward `Q` again.

Clearly the implementation cannot “slide” points, so for each triangle involving `C`, for each vertex `S` of that triangle other than `C`, store the points inside the triangle in a binary search tree sorted by angle with `S`. These structures suffice to implement this kinetic algorithm.

I assert without proof that this algorithm is correct.

As for the running time, each event is a point-line intersection and can be handled in time `O(log n)`. The angles `PC` and `QC` and `RC` are all monotonic, so each of `O(1)` lines hits each point at most once.

Comment: I foresee evil corner cases when CP hits multiple points instead of only one.

Comment: @missingno That's the degeneracy that I assumed away, as is standard in computational geometry. It's not possible to solve the problem in general when there can be three collinear points.

Comment: Thats the degenaracy that I assumed in, as is standard in programming contests :) But I am now fully convinced since the colinear case doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @missingo: Indeed, the case of colinear points is not considered in the original problem.

Comment: If CPQ has n points and then you slide C towards Q, the triangle CPQ loses points while you are sliding. Why does the CPQ slide at the end still contain n points?

Answer (score 2):

Main idea is: if we have got the line, we can try to find a point on it using linear search. If the line is not good enough, we can move it using binary search.

[image]

1. Sort the points based on the direction from vertex `A`. Sort them for `B` and `C` too.
2. Set current range for vertex `A` to be all the points.
3. Select 2 middle points from the range for vertex `A`. These 2 points define subrange for 'A'. Get some line `AD` lying between these points.
4. Iterate for all the points lying between `B` and `AD` (starting from `BA`). Stop when `n` points found. Select subrange of directions from `B` to points `n` and next after `n` (if there is no point after `n`, use `BC`). If less than `n` points can be found, set current range for vertex `A` to be the left half of the current range and go to step 3.
5. Same as step 4, but for vertex `C`.
6. If subranges `A`, `B`, `C` intersect, choose any point from there and finish. Otherwise, if `A&B` is closer to `A`, set current range for vertex `A` to be the right half of the current range and go to step 3. Otherwise set current range for vertex `A` to be the left half of the current range and go to step 3.

Complexity: sorting `O(n * log n)`, search `O(n * log n)`. (Combination of binary and linear search).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that takes O(log n) passes of cost n each.

Each pass starts with an initial point, which divides the triangle into there subtriangles. If each has n points, we are finished. If not, consider the subtriangle which is furthest away from the desired n. Suppose it has too many, just for now. The imbalances sum to zero, so at least one of the other two subtriangles has too few points. The third subtriangle either also has too few, or has exactly n points - or the original subtriangle would not have the highest discrepancy.

Take the most imbalanced subtriangle and consider moving the centre point along the line leading away from it. As you do so, the imbalance of the most imbalanced point will reduce. For each point in the triangle, you can work out when that point crosses into or out of the most imbalanced subtriangle as you move the centre point. Therefore you can work out in time n where to move the centre point to give the most imbalanced triangle any desired count.

As you move the centre point you can choose whether points move in our out of the most imbalanced subtriangle, but you can't chose which of the other two subtriangles they go to, or from - but you can predict which easily from which side of the line along which you are sliding the centre point they live, so you can move the centre point along this line to get the lowest maximum discrepancy after the move. In the worst case, all of the points moved go into, or out of, the subtriangle that was exactly balanced. However, if the imbalanced subtriangle has n + k points, by moving k/2 of them, you can move, at worst, to the case where it and the previously balanced subtriangle are out by k/2. The third subtriangle may still be unbalanced by up to k, in the other direction, but in this case a second pass will reduce the maximum imbalance to something below k/2.

Therefore in the case of a large unbalance, we can reduce it by at worst a constant factor in two passes of the above algorithm, so in O(log n) passes the imbalance will be small enough that we are into special cases where we worry about an excess of at most one point. Here I am going to guess that the number of such special cases is practically enumerable in a program, and the cost amounts to a small constant addition.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a linear time algorithm. See the last paragraph of the paper "Illumination by floodlights- by Steiger and Streinu". Their algorithm works for any k1, k2, k3 that sum up to n. Therefore, k1=k2=k3=n/3 is a special case.

Here is the link where you can find the article. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772197000278 a CiteSeerX link is http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.4634

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. This answer does not really help that much. Could you elaborate on why this article is important for this problem? Is it possible to quote the article? Can you provide a link to the article abstract or full text?

Comment: Thanks vidstige, I have added the links.