# Dynamically arrange elements in triangle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, geometry

I'm looking for a JS function to dynamically arrange elements in triangle like in this picture:

[image]

The number of elements will depend on user choices, so it will be different every time.
I managed to do it for a circle, but seems to be quite tricky for a triangle.

Comment: I tried to work from this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964103/triangle-partitioning

Comment: Also tried to make three lines and rotate each to form a triangle. Gives quite good results, but i was wondering if there was a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function drawTriangle(ctx, sideLength) {
  var i = 0, direction = 1;

  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  for (; i < 3; i += 1) {
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / -3);
    ctx.lineTo(direction * sideLength, 0);
    ctx.translate(direction * sideLength, 0);
    direction *= -1;
  }

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();
}

function drawCircle(ctx) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true); 
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
}

function drawCircles(ctx, num, sideLength) {
  var stepLength = (sideLength * 3) / num, i = 0;

  ctx.save();
  for (; i < num; i += 1) {
    if ((stepLength * i) % sideLength === 0) {
      ctx.rotate(2 * Math.PI / 3);
    }

    drawCircle(ctx);
    ctx.translate(-stepLength, 0);
  }

  ctx.restore();
}

var
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  sideLength = 200;

if (ctx) {
  ctx.translate(50, 225);
  drawTriangle(ctx, sideLength);
  drawCircles(ctx, 14 * 3, sideLength);
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ej2Kq/

Answer (score 1):

On the picture it is clearly seen that only certain numbers of elements can be arranged in such a way. The number should be divisible by 3. First - check for that precondition. Then split the total amount of elements that you have in three groups and spread each group evenly across each of the borders.

Comment: Thanks. I have already done the part for the number to be divisible by 3. How do I spread a group across the borders?

Comment: 101 how to draw a triangle =)

Comment: What about just going on a border, placing the tokens in equal steps? You should have the coordinates of both the ends of the border (which you definitely have because you are drawing the triangle) and know the amount of elements to place so that you can do that in equal steps.

Comment: So for now I came up with this:

https://gist.github.com/37ab614a8e17f06960d2

It does the job, but I don't like having to manually add the last circle.
Working on improving this.

Answer (score 0):

So for now I came up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBVFL/

It does the job, but I don't like having to manually add the last circle.